# How can I split string to array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have the string like this, I am not able to change it, it's comming from remote API.

```
"[TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=180, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=66, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=31:75:2.224]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=148, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=96, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY], time=30:74:147.66]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=141, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=240, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=1:168:105.70]]]"
```

I would like to split it as it would be JSON array (the one from API has no quotes for example). I want my output to be:

```
[
 "TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=180, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=66, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], 
 time=31:75:2.224]]",
 "TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=148, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=96, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY], 
 time=30:74:147.66]]",
 "TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=141, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=240, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], 
 time=1:168:105.70]]"
]
```

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot

Comment: While you may be using TypeScript to do this, it doesn't seem to have much to do with TypeScript (or angular either).  Instead, I'd say this is more "javascript" and "parsing".

Comment: Do you have any documentation about the API? Is it possible for the keys or values to contain a (possibly escaped) `[` or `]` character?

Comment: No, there won't be any brackets in keys and values. I've updated a question, thanks

Comment: I don't envy you, this is hard to parse.  I would really try to fix the API.  It seems like the API is using Python, and is returning a visual representation of the object.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to get rid of the surrounding `[]` with a `slice` from 1 to length-1. Then replace where you want to split with an easier split demarking character so you can keep `]` and `T` (I used `-` but it could be any unique character). Then split on that unique character.

```js
let result='[TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=180, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=66, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=31:75:2.224]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=148, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=96, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY], time=30:74:147.66]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=141, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=240, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=1:168:105.70]]]'

result =result.slice(1,result.length-1).replace(/\], T/,']-T').split('-')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an horrible API response. But here a way to process that specific one.

The information you need to retreive are:

- year
- month
- day
- dayOfWeek
- time

You can use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to retreive every information in individual arrays... Then use a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to build an array of objects...

```js
let APIresponse =
  "[TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=180, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=66, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=31:75:2.224]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=148, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=96, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY], time=30:74:147.66]], TimeStamp [choice=DateTime [date=Date [year=141, month=UNSPECIFIED, day=240, dayOfWeek=UNSPECIFIED], time=1:168:105.70]]]";

function weirdAPItoJSON(response) {
  
  // Count how many occurance of "TimeStamp"
  let occurances = response.match(/TimeStamp/g)
  
  console.log(`${occurances.length} timeStamps... Let's retreive all parts.`)
  
  // =======
  let years = response.match(/year=\d{1,3}/g)
  console.log(years)
  
  // =======
  let months = response.match(/month=[a-z A-Z]{1,}/g)
  console.log(months)
  
  // =======
  let days = response.match(/day=\d{1,3}/g)
  console.log(days)
  
  // =======
  let daysOfWeek = response.match(/dayOfWeek=[a-z A-Z]{1,}/g)
  console.log(months)
  
  // =======
  let times = response.match(/time=\d{1,}:\d{1,}:\d{1,}\.\d{1,}/g)
  console.log(times)
  
  // ============= Build the resulting array of objects
  let result = []
  
  occurances.forEach(function(item, index){
    result[index] = {}
    result[index].year = parseInt(years[index].split("=")[1])
    result[index].month = months[index].split("=")[1]
    result[index].day = parseInt(days[index].split("=")[1])
    result[index].dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[index].split("=")[1]
    result[index].time = times[index].split("=")[1]
  })
  
  return result
}

let result = weirdAPItoJSON(APIresponse)
console.log("\nResult:")
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```